# How to call a function defined in an array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Following is my code which is throwing an error when I am trying to console the function defined in the array. Let me know what I am doing wrong.

```
var a = ['This is a string', {'name': 'Test User'}, 90, undefined, 'Another String', null, function(){return 'This is also valid'}];

for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  if(typeof a[i] === 'function')
    console.log(a[i]());
  else
    console.log(a[i]());
}
```

Getting error -

```
TypeError: a[i] is not a function
```

Comment: Check `else` part. Do you need to call it as function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

remove the method call from else

```
for(var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
  if(typeof a[i] === 'function')
    console.log(a[i]());
  else
    console.log(a[i]); //remove method call from here
}
```

Comment: @Tushar you answered the question infact 20 seconds before me. It will give an error if the method is not a function type.